# Connecting data from an array to an object to transform its value with a middleman

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What would be the best way to use `queued_Dr` to alter its values like `upcoming_appointments.PCD` by using `all_appointments`?

What would be the best approach to this problem?

```js
var queued_Dr = ["Dr.Salazar","Dr.Connors","Dr.Johnson","Dr.Pearson"]


upcoming_appointments =
[{"DOB":"01-27-2002","name":"Judy, W." ,"PCD":"Dr-S"}
    ,{"DOB":"08-15-1995","name":"John, V." ,"PCD":"Dr-C"}
    ,{"DOB":"07-05-1992","name":"David, C.","PCD":"Dr-S"}
    ,{"DOB":"01-15-2002","name":"Anna, S." ,"PCD":"Dr-J"}
    ,{"DOB":"01-15-2002","name":"Jeff, D." ,"PCD":"Dr-P"}]


all_appointments = 
[["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],
 ["Dr-C","Austin","Dr.Connors"],
 ["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"],
 ["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],
 ["Dr-P","San Juan","Dr.Pearson"],
 ["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"]]
```

Input:

```
queued_Dr = ["Dr.Salazar","Dr.Connors","Dr.Johnson","Dr.Pearson"]
```

Desired Output:

```
queued_Dr = ["Dr-S","Dr-C","Dr-J","Dr-P"]
```

Actual Output:

```
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Attempt

```js
const mapTo = (arrayWithNames) => {
  var newArray = []; 
  return arrayWithNames.map(name => {
    const appointment = Object.values(all_appointments)
      .find(appointment => appointment[2] === name);
      newArray.push(appointment[0]);
  })
  return newArray;
}
const result = mapTo(queued_Dr)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `upcoming_appointments`? I can't see it referred to anywhere. Also you stated you want to 'alter' some values, but looking at your desired output there is no altered data, it's just a list of `PCD`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is to find the name in all_appointments and return the corresponding abbreviation.

The second solution is to just compose the abbreviation without other arrays.

```js
const queued_Dr = ["Dr.Salazar","Dr.Connors","Dr.Johnson","Dr.Pearson"];

const all_appointments = [["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],["Dr-C","Austin","Dr.Connors"],["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"],["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],["Dr-P","San Juan","Dr.Pearson"],["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"]];
 
const result1 = queued_Dr
  .map((queu) => all_appointments
    .find((appointment) => appointment.at(-1) === queu)
    .at(0));
    
console.log(result1);


const result2 = queued_Dr
  .map((queu) => {
    const [abbr, name] =  queu.split('.');
    return `${abbr}-${name.at(0)}`;
  });
  
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```